# Recover as virtual machine to any host in DPM 2010 missing in Recovery option

Tags: hyper-v-server-2008-r2, scdpm

I have DPM 2010 installed and when choosing Recovery (Bare Metal Recovery) I don't have an option to `Recover as virtual machine to any host`. I only have option copy to network folder available. Is there anything I need to do prior to getting this option available?

`DPM 2010` is installed on physical host. No Hyper-V role is installed on it. Maybe that's the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get that option machine has to be backed up from `Hyper-V HOST` side and not from the machine itself (Bare Metal Recovery or not). So DPM client has to be installed on `Hyper-V Host` and backup done from there. Otherwise the option is not visible.